# Identify innermost child element using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

There is already data in a table on the page.The structure of the table looks like

```html
<table id='tbl1'>
  <tr>
    <td><div>some val</div></td><td><div>some val</div></td><td><div>some val</div></td></tr>
  <tr>
    <td><div>some val</div></td></tr>
</table>
```

that is few rows will be displayed from db in above format. In addition to it, based on a button click(Add new row),a new row needs to be be populated.I have implemented the 'add' functionality with this:

```
$('#tbl1'.append(<tr><td><div><input type='text id='bc' value=''/></div>           </td></tr>
```

Rows are getting added successfully. But I need to input a value into the above text field(identified by id:'bc') and based on the value enterted, the matching data should be fetched from DB.

I thought if I get the id of the innermost element,I will be able to capture that value and send it to DB)**Am trying to fetch the ID 'bc' AS**

```
$('#bc'.keyup(function(){
    alert("key pressed");
});
```

But,am not getting the alert...I am pretty new to jquery. Please suggest ways of doing it.

Comment: Could you please share some code of your current page and some info on what you have tried so far and where you ran into problems? Right now what you are asking is a bit too vague.

Comment: Have added the code properly. Let me know if u need further details please.

Answer (score 0):

First, your code is full of syntax errors. As it is now, it won't work at all:

```
$('#tbl1'.append(<tr><td><div><input type='text id='bc' value=''/></div></td></tr>
```

- your jQuery selector and append function aren't closed `$('#tbl1'` -> `$('#tbl1')`
- your your appended html isn't a string
- the type='text attribute is missing the closing quote
- Id's have to be unique. You're appending inputs with the same id.
- your table has 4 columns but you're appending a row with only one

Now your problem with the keyup is, that inputs are added to the DOM after page load, so you can't user `.keyup()` in that case. Instead use [`.on()`](https://api.jquery.com/on/) on the table for example like that:

```
$('#tbl1').append('<tr><td colspan="4"><div><input type="text" class="bc" value=""/></div></td></tr>');

$('#tbl1').on('keyup','.bc',function(){
    alert("key pressed");
});
```

Comment: Thanks Andy...it's not the as-is code.. I just typed in few lines so that it would give some information of the question.